# How to sort 2d array by first, then second, then third, ... columns using C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, armadillo

I have an array in C++ that looks like

```
95 52
95 20
95 67
76 25
76 250
```

and I want to sort it by the first column, and then by the second. In general, I may have $n$ columns so I may need a recursive function. Anyone have any fast and efficient ways of doing this? The end goal is to get a list of the unique rows.

Comment: can you specify whether your array is a 2-D C-style array, or a C-style array of pointers, or a standard container, or what?  (show its declaration)

Answer (score 4):

Put the data in a vector of vectors, and use `std::sort`:

```
vector<vector<int> > vv;
// Put data in the vector...
vector<int> v3 = {95, 67};
vv.push_back(v3);
vector<int> v4 = {76, 25};
vv.push_back(v4);
vector<int> v1 = {95, 52};
vv.push_back(v1);
vector<int> v2 = {95, 20};
vv.push_back(v2);
vector<int> v5 = {76, 250};
vv.push_back(v5);
// Sort the data
sort(vv.begin(), vv.end());
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/lCUezC)

`std::vector` comparison is lexicographic, it works regardless of the number of items in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to sort the array, taking column 1 as main index, column 2 as secondary, etc, AND GET THE FINAL RESULT.

   An custom sort function will do the work.

   ```
   struct SortAll {
       bool operator() (int *item1, int *item2) {
           for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_COUNT; ++i) {
               if (item1[i] < item2[i]) {
                   return true;
               } else if (item1[i] > item2[i]) {
                   return false;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
   } sort_all;
   ```
2. If you want to sort the array, specifying which column to sort, AND GET ONE RESULT EACH TIME.

   Create a sort object each time you want to sort.

   ```
   struct SortEach {
   public:
       SortEach(int column) : column(column) { }
       bool operator() (int *item1, int *item2) {
           return item1[column] < item2[column];
       }
   private:
       int column;
   }
   ```

Usage:

```
int arr[LENGTH][COLUMN_COUNT];
SortEach sort_2(2);
std::sort(&arr[0], &arr[LENGTH], sort_all); // sort by all column
std::sort(&arr[0], &arr[LENGTH], sort_2); // sort by column 2
```

Comment: I don't believe (1) works. It seems like it would just return true as soon as one of the items in the columns is less than another. I want to sort by the first column and then, if any indices are the same for the first, sort by the second, and so on.